# Entity Framework - Creating an abstraction layer in ASP .NET WebForms

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, webforms

Currently in our application our convention for loading and saving data is using object.Load() and object.Save() functions that execute stored procedures. Is there a way to import entity framework and keep the same convention?

For example, so far the only way I found seems to be oEntity.Database_Table.Find(ID) for loads and oEntity.SaveChanges() for saves. Is there a way I can simplify/abstract this functionality?

Comment: You'd miss out on most of the benefits of EF if you did that.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Can you elaborate a bit? I'm very interested in understanding why.

Comment: Having objects with .Save() and .Load() is just really old-fashioned.  EF has a Change Tracker enables you to load, change, and Save graphs of related objects, instead of individual objects.  And it allows your Entities to be free of Data Access cruft.

Comment: Also if you just want to call stored procedures and map the results to objects, use Dapper instead of EF. https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper